# Context object is empty while receiving POST request , in Koa?

Tags: node.js, koa

I am new in Koa and I am creating a demo app. I want to create an API to handle POST request, But when I `console.log(ctx);` then there is nothing in `ctx` in `indexRouter.js`, the console only printing empty object like `{}`.

I don't know why this is happening. Please anyone suggest me where I am doing wrong?
And please help me to get the `request.body` by `POST` Method.

**serverKoa.js:**

```
var koa = require('koa');
var router = require('koa-router');
var app = new koa();
var route = router(); //Instantiate the router

app.use(route.routes()); //Use the routes defined using the router
const index = require('./router/indexRouter')(route);

app.listen(3005 ,function(){
console.log("\n\nKoa server is running on port: 3005");
});
```

**indexRouter.js:**

```
var indexController=require('../controller/indexController');
module.exports = function (route) {
    route.post('/postnew',async ( ctx, next) => {
    console.log(ctx); // here  printing {}
  });
}
```

**and my request object ( by postman ) is:**

```
Method: POST,
url:http://localhost:3005/postnew
body:{
    "firstName":"viki",
    "lastName":"Kumar",
    "userName":"vk12kq14",
    "password":"098765432"
}
content-type:application/json
```

[image: POSTMAN]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code has two issues:

- you're not using the "next" version of `koa-router`, which is required if you want to use `async/await`. You can install it like this:

  ```
  npm i koa-router@next --save
  ```
- you're not using `koa-bodyparser` to parse the request data:

  ```
  npm i koa-bodyparser --save
  ```

To use:

```
var koa        = require('koa');
var router     = require('koa-router');
var bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');

var app        = new koa();
app.use(bodyParser());
...
```

The parsed body data will be available in your route handlers as `ctx.request.body`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help today. You saved my time. Thank you so much .
It works for me .

Comment: It doesn't work